# Adding RAM to a laptop with internal battery

Tags: laptop, memory

I heard recommendations everywhere that before you insert a second RAM to a laptop, it is best to take out the battery. However, the laptop I own (Dell Inspiron 1528S) has an internal battery. Am I supposed to find a way to disconnect the battery before I add the RAM?

Comment: You mean the CLOCKs internal battery?  don't worry about it..

Comment: @Tyson I think he means the main battery. Many, many laptops nowadays use an internal battery, because that lets you make them a bit thinner.

Comment: The concern is that you don't want power to the RAM when you insert or remove it.  As long as the computer is shut down, you're OK.  Use static electricity precautions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything about an Inspiron 1528S model. However, under the assumption it's a 15" ultrabook (generally, internal batteries are most common on ultrabooks), then it might be the 15z 5523. In that case, the [manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15z-5523_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf) says to hold the power button down for 5 seconds after shutting down the computer, but otherwise not to worry about removing the battery (that's a much more involved process).

Even if it's not that specific model, the general principle holds: in many computers with an internal battery, disconnecting the battery is more involved than replacing RAM. In that case, don't worry about the battery so much; just be careful to disconnect it from the *wall*.

Edit: As Ramhound points out, Dell is very good about releasing manuals for their computers. The best thing to do for *any* computer is to follow the manual; other advice is necessarily general, while the manual is how the manufacturer intends *that computer* to be serviced.

Comment: If anything there is always a service manual for these devices.  You should always verify them before doing anything

Comment: @cpast Thanks. This model is probably only found in China. It is not a ultrabook. Here is an [image](http://img10.360buyimg.com/n1/g16/M00/0B/16/rBEbRlN-vtsIAAAAAAFXjRqZQIIAACRpQK40ngAAVel091.jpg). I will download their manual and take a look.

Comment: @cpast Following your suggestion, I downloaded their user manual pdf which clearly instructed me to take out the battery as the first step and then work on the RAM. Thanks again!